# webistrano alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, webistrano

We are looking for a automated remote  deployment system for our Rails deployments. Are there any good alternatives to Webistrano. We want try out first and select which will best suit our requirements.

Comment: Have a look at kwatee (http://www.kwatee.net)

Answer (score 4):

Etsy have [open sourced](https://github.com/etsy/deployinator) their [Deployinator](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2010/05/20/quantum-of-deployment/). It uses Sinatra, Capistrano and a little PHP, but you can deploy anything from it.

Answer (score 3):

[Strano](https://github.com/joelmoss/strano) - GitHub-powered web UI for Capistrano deployment. Works with non-GitHub projects as well.

Answer (score 2):

After long time search, I've started building Gunnery - a real, modern [webistrano alternative](http://eyjafjallajokull.github.io/gunnery/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still relevant but I would like to come up with a different solution. I am building a new deployment tool that does just what you are looking for.
I do not intend to spam my stuff here but since I am building something that could help you...

Anyway, have a look here https://alessiosantocs.github.io/Captain. I'm gathering feedback so if you have any please let me know.